# How to style a video player in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add flags on the video progress bar, so when the user drag the scrubber over the flags, the texts will popup over the flags.

I have something like

```
 <video width="720" height="640" controls>
    <source src='/assets/video/test.mp4' type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

my control bar.

```
           flag 1    flag 2
play |D-------------------------   volume fullscreen
```

`|D` is the scrubber so when I drag it over flag 1, the texts will show on top of it. It seems like every browser has different default video player and I am not sure how it can be done. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!